# Scary "Authorization required" message while users try running my script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am developing a Google Apps Script, which I think to share to "anyone with the link." The script is supposed to process some documents in the users' Google Drive periodically. For this, my users are supposed to create a time-driven trigger.

But while someone tries to run the script, he gets a warning with red border: "Authorization required ..." The warning seemed scary, and I was afraid if it might drive away my users.

Wanted to know if there is any way to avoid or soften the warning. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the share. Get users to share the docs in question with an account that you setup. That way they can avoid the warning. Also means, if you change the code, they don't need to switch to the new version.

Comment: Good alternative, but quota will be an issue. Is there anything like "scripts from some privileged google account, say Business App Account, will not yield this warning?" Thanks.

Comment: I did suggest this a while back.   .... To get round the "malicious script" problem. 
It would be nice to have a named script pool. The script pool would have a unique name so that documents can be shared with it. I could then share spreadsheets and docs etc with the named script pool.  Maybe I should file it as a feature request.

Comment: feature request: http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1709

Comment: This is similar to a feature request I submitted, so you might be interested in starring it http://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=1249&q=trusted&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner

Answer (score 2):

You can't avoid the message because your users have to know what your script will access and what it will not.

What you can do instead is have your application run under your authority so that it uses your credentials, documents and quota. That way, your users will not see the warning.